# Why is this package (pdfc-gui) updates my ca-certificates, on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, certificates

I am trying to figure out if an application I installed can be trusted, based on the following output. I hope this is the correct platform to get some advice on the matter!

I installed this package (**pdfc-gui**) from [here](https://www.inetsoftware.de/products/pdf-content-comparer) with:

`sudo dpkg -i pdfc-gui-21.4.225.deb`

and in the installation I see that it adds/updates ssl certificates (see install output below).
Unfortunately I don't understand linux well enough to be sure if this is something I should worry about.

**Can anyone explain this output to me?**

Should I remove the package, and if so, how to be sure that all the changes it did would truely be reverted?

```
sudo dpkg -i pdfc-gui-21.4.225.deb
Selecting previously unselected package pdfc-gui.
(Reading database ... 734495 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack pdfc-gui-21.4.225.deb ...
Unpacking pdfc-gui (21.4.225) ...
Setting up pdfc-gui (21.4.225) ...
Clearing symlinks in /etc/ssl/certs...
done.
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
129 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

Replacing debian:ACCVRAIZ1.pem
Replacing debian:Actalis_Authentication_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:AffirmTrust_Commercial.pem
Replacing debian:AffirmTrust_Networking.pem
Replacing debian:AffirmTrust_Premium.pem
Replacing debian:AffirmTrust_Premium_ECC.pem
Replacing debian:Atos_TrustedRoot_2011.pem
Replacing debian:Autoridad_de_Certificacion_Firmaprofesional_CIF_A62634068.pem
Replacing debian:Baltimore_CyberTrust_Root.pem
Replacing debian:Buypass_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:Buypass_Class_3_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:CA_Disig_Root_R2.pem
Replacing debian:CFCA_EV_ROOT.pem
Replacing debian:COMODO_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:COMODO_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:COMODO_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:Certigna.pem
Replacing debian:Certum_Trusted_Network_CA.pem
Replacing debian:Chambers_of_Commerce_Root_-_2008.pem
Replacing debian:Comodo_AAA_Services_root.pem
Replacing debian:Cybertrust_Global_Root.pem
Replacing debian:D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_2009.pem
Replacing debian:D-TRUST_Root_Class_3_CA_2_EV_2009.pem
Replacing debian:DST_Root_CA_X3.pem
Replacing debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G2.pem
Replacing debian:DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G3.pem
Replacing debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem
Replacing debian:DigiCert_Global_Root_G3.pem
Replacing debian:DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:DigiCert_Trusted_Root_G4.pem
Replacing debian:E-Tugra_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:EC-ACC.pem
Replacing debian:Entrust.net_Premium_2048_Secure_Server_CA.pem
Replacing debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_EC1.pem
Replacing debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
Replacing debian:GeoTrust_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem
Replacing debian:GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R4.pem
Replacing debian:GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R5.pem
Replacing debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.pem
Replacing debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R3.pem
Replacing debian:Global_Chambersign_Root_-_2008.pem
Replacing debian:Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.pem
Replacing debian:Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Replacing debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2011.pem
Replacing debian:Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_1.pem
Replacing debian:IdenTrust_Commercial_Root_CA_1.pem
Replacing debian:IdenTrust_Public_Sector_Root_CA_1.pem
Replacing debian:Izenpe.com.pem
Replacing debian:Microsec_e-Szigno_Root_CA_2009.pem
Replacing debian:NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_Főtanúsítvány.pem
Replacing debian:Network_Solutions_Certificate_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GB_CA.pem
Replacing debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_1_G3.pem
Replacing debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.pem
Replacing debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_2_G3.pem
Replacing debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_3.pem
Replacing debian:QuoVadis_Root_CA_3_G3.pem
Replacing debian:SecureSign_RootCA11.pem
Replacing debian:SecureTrust_CA.pem
Replacing debian:Secure_Global_CA.pem
Replacing debian:Security_Communication_RootCA2.pem
Replacing debian:Security_Communication_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:Sonera_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_EV_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
Replacing debian:Starfield_Class_2_CA.pem
Replacing debian:Starfield_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Replacing debian:Starfield_Services_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem
Replacing debian:SwissSign_Gold_CA_-_G2.pem
Replacing debian:SwissSign_Silver_CA_-_G2.pem
Replacing debian:T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_2.pem
Replacing debian:T-TeleSec_GlobalRoot_Class_3.pem
Replacing debian:TWCA_Global_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:TWCA_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:TeliaSonera_Root_CA_v1.pem
Replacing debian:Trustis_FPS_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:USERTrust_ECC_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:VeriSign_Universal_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:XRamp_Global_CA_Root.pem
Replacing debian:certSIGN_ROOT_CA.pem
Replacing debian:ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM.pem
Replacing debian:Amazon_Root_CA_1.pem
Replacing debian:Amazon_Root_CA_2.pem
Replacing debian:Amazon_Root_CA_3.pem
Replacing debian:Amazon_Root_CA_4.pem
Replacing debian:Certum_Trusted_Network_CA_2.pem
Replacing debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_ECC_RootCA_2015.pem
Replacing debian:Hellenic_Academic_and_Research_Institutions_RootCA_2015.pem
Replacing debian:ISRG_Root_X1.pem
Replacing debian:SZAFIR_ROOT_CA2.pem
Replacing debian:TUBITAK_Kamu_SM_SSL_Kok_Sertifikasi_-_Surum_1.pem
Replacing debian:GDCA_TrustAUTH_R5_ROOT.pem
Replacing debian:GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R6.pem
Replacing debian:OISTE_WISeKey_Global_Root_GC_CA.pem
Replacing debian:SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
Replacing debian:SSL.com_EV_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA_R2.pem
Replacing debian:SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
Replacing debian:SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_RSA.pem
Replacing debian:TrustCor_ECA-1.pem
Replacing debian:TrustCor_RootCert_CA-1.pem
Replacing debian:TrustCor_RootCert_CA-2.pem
Replacing debian:Certigna_Root_CA.pem
Replacing debian:certSIGN_Root_CA_G2.pem
Replacing debian:emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_C3.pem
Replacing debian:emSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
Replacing debian:emSign_Root_CA_-_C1.pem
Replacing debian:emSign_Root_CA_-_G1.pem
Replacing debian:Entrust_Root_Certification_Authority_-_G4.pem
Replacing debian:e-Szigno_Root_CA_2017.pem
Replacing debian:GTS_Root_R1.pem
Replacing debian:GTS_Root_R2.pem
Replacing debian:GTS_Root_R3.pem
Replacing debian:GTS_Root_R4.pem
Replacing debian:Hongkong_Post_Root_CA_3.pem
Replacing debian:Microsoft_ECC_Root_Certificate_Authority_2017.pem
Replacing debian:Microsoft_RSA_Root_Certificate_Authority_2017.pem
Replacing debian:Trustwave_Global_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:Trustwave_Global_ECC_P256_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:Trustwave_Global_ECC_P384_Certification_Authority.pem
Replacing debian:UCA_Extended_Validation_Root.pem
Replacing debian:UCA_Global_G2_Root.pem
Replacing debian:NAVER_Global_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
done.
done.
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1.1) ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program calls this in its `postinst` script:

```
update-ca-certificates -f 2>/dev/null
```

The `-f` flag:

> -f, --fresh
> Fresh updates. Remove symlinks in /etc/ssl/certs directory.

So the output matches that of a call to `update-ca-certificates`. Note that there were other triggers, so that the certificates update might have been waiting there, from another unrelated installation/update, and were only now processed.

You can inspect the contents of the `deb` file with:

```
ar -x packages.deb
```

The (un)install scripts are then inside `control.tar.xz` (at least for version 2.0 of the Debian binary package format).

That being said, there is no way on earth to trust a closed source application. If it were doing something shady, you probably wouldn't see it in the output (changing CA certificates would be definitely shady, but it doesn't seem to be the case).